# Row Sum and Case insensitivity

Tags: sql-server

By having a table with thousands of Villages of course there are duplicates. In order to use them as mapping table it's necessary to mark them accordingly.

Table looks as follows;

| id | country | name | notUnique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | Peru | Arenal | null |
| 1234568 | Mexico | Arenal | null |
| 1234569 | Honduras | Arenal | null |
| 1234570 | USA | Pasadena | null |
| 1234571 | Canada | Pasadena | null |
| 1234572 | Philippines | Pasadeña | null |
| 1234573 | Poland | Susk Nowy | null |

now I use my code snippet to fill out the not Unique:

```
-- generate RowSum:
update
    Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal
set
    notUnique = 1
from
    Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal osm
 join   (
        SELECT [name], COUNT([name]) RowSum
        FROM Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal osm
        Group by [name]
        ) cnt
    on osm.[name] = cnt.[name]
where cnt.RowSum > 1
go
```

obviously it results in result bellow, as there is no case insensitivity;

| id | country | name | notUnique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | Peru | Arenal | 1 |
| 1234568 | Mexico | Arenal | 1 |
| 1234569 | Honduras | Arenal | 1 |
| 1234570 | USA | Pasadena | 1 |
| 1234571 | Canada | Pasadena | 1 |
| 1234572 | Philippines | Pasadeña | null |
| 1234573 | Poland | Susk Nowy | null |

To include 'Pasadeña' in my result groups of the 'Pasadena' I tried to add a `collate Latin1_General_CI_AI`. That is the point where I fail. Any help is highly welcome.

Comment: What is the output you actually want here, assuming your current result is not right?

Comment: I expect to have the 'Pasadeña' of the Philippines as 'notUnique = 1' as well as there are others but with missing accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by @TimBiegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69618759/14868997), you should use a case-insensitive collation.

But you can do this more simply with an updatable CTE

```sql
WITH osm AS (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY (name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)) RowSum
    FROM Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal osm
)
UPDATE osm
SET
    notUnique = 1
WHERE osm.RowSum > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `COLLATE` on the `name` column, along with exists logic:

```sql
UPDATE Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal o1
SET notUnique = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Mapping.dbo.OsmGlobal t2
              WHERE t2.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI =
                    t1.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AND
                    t2.id <> t1.id);
```

In plain English, the above query says to set the `notUnique` flag to 1 for any record for which we can find another record (different `id`) having the *same* name, as collated using `Latin1_General_CI_AI`.

Comment: Did you know you only need to specify `COLLATE` once in an expression or comparison, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#collation-rules